# Get remote errors in Service Fabric using Web Api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, azure-service-fabric

Web API has `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy 
= IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;` to turn on remote errors.  (Allowing them to see them in a browser even if you are not browsing on the local machine.

But, near as I can tell, Service Fabric, running Web Api, does not support `GlobalConfiguration`.

**Is there a way to configure things so I don't have to log into one of my Service Fabric server machines each time I want to see what a services error message is?**

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you don't show error details to everyone. 
It's a security risk.

Consider moving your error logs out of your cluster. For instance, by using [OMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-service-fabric), [ELK](https://logz.io/learn/complete-guide-elk-stack/) or [Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-core) Insights.

Comment: Good advice. I should have mentioned that this is a Development Environment cluster. In my Dev cluster, digging through monitoring or logging tools just adds overhead to development efforts.